# Creating Boundary Boxes off a Image which has highlighted text removed

Tags: python

```
import cv2
import pytesseract as pyt
pyt.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread('Image Pasted at 2021-10-21 13-31.png')

img  = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

img = img[:,:,2]
hImg, wImg, = img.shape

boxes = pyt.image_to_boxes(img)
# print(boxes)

for b in boxes.splitlines():
    # print(b)
    b = b.split(' ')
    print(b)

    x,y,w,h = int(b[1]),int(b[2]),int(b[3]),int(b[4])

    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),1)


cv2.imshow('Result', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the code im using for trying to convert an image (some of which is highlighted) to string.  I'm getting an error when trying to create the boundary boxes..

```
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y), (x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),3)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4-dev) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'rectangle'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
>  - Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
```

Anyone know how to fix this?  I think the issue has to do with the "COLOR_BGR2HSV" and img[:,:,2] line...

Comment: What makes you think `img = img[:,:,2]` is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure, i guess thats the only way I tried and it seems to work.  Would there be a better way?

Comment: I assume you would be able to `imshow` the original `img`.  Can you "undo" what `img = img[:,:,2]` does to get a proper argument to `imshow`?

Comment: https://ibb.co/R9vsQKb.  this is the original picture. 

after COLOR_BGR2HSV & img[:,:,2] 
https://ibb.co/b3JhWbB

Comment: The instruction in the error message does not appear in the posted code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that... I am still getting the error

Comment: Check the expected arguments of the cv2.rectangle function.  Also note that the error message's last argument is 3, in the code it is 1.